# How to replace multiple columns in one SQL query?

Tags: sql, left-join

I have 2 tables: `country` and `trip`.

A trip can have up to 3 country codes.

**country** table

| country_code | country_name |
| --- | --- |
| FRA | FRANCE |
| IRL | IRELAND |
| JPN | JAPAN |
| MAR | MOROCCO |
| NZL | NEW ZEALAND |

**trip** table

| trip_id | country_code | country_code2 | country_code3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FRA | IRL | JPN |
| 2 | MAR | NZL |  |

My goal is to have country names displayed on the trip table instead of country codes.

I succeed to have only 1 country code replaced, thanks to the left join clause. I would like to have up to 3 country names displayed per row.

```
SELECT trip_id, country_name
FROM trip
LEFT JOIN country ON country_code = country_name
```

The actual output of the trip table:

| trip_id | country_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FRANCE |
| 2 | MOROCCO |

Is there a way to replace each country code with its corresponding country name?

The EXPECTED output of the query from the `trip` table:

| trip_id | country_name | country_name2 | country_name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FRANCE | IRELAND | JAPAN |
| 2 | MOROCCO | NEW ZEALAND |  |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way of accomplishing this query is using subqueries:

```
SELECT t.trip_id, 
       (SELECT country_name FROM country WHERE country_code =  t.country_code) "c1",
       (SELECT country_name FROM country WHERE country_code = t.countty_code2) "c2",
       (SELECT country_name FROM country WHERE country_code = t.country_code3) "c3"
FROM trip t
```

Comment: for lots of rows this will be a very slow solution

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gonnen! it works perfectly! I like the structure of this query. It is very clean :)

Answer (score 2):

You could add two more joins

```
SELECT trip_id, c1.country_name, c2.country_name, c3.country_name
FROM trip t
left join 
country c1
on t.country_code = c1.country_code
left join 
country c2
on t.country_code2 = c2.country_code
left join 
country c3
on t.country_code3 = c3.country_code
```

Comment: Man, this is the answer! Thank you so much! I can't believe you did it in no time!